# python version confliction while accesing yum command

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, yum

My amazon aws system has two python, 2.6 and 2.7

Default python which I say `which python` is : `Python 2.7.9`

I also set symbolic link using

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

When I do

```
yum
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

also

```
echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin
```

I guess python 2.6 and 2.7 linked togather?

is there any way to get rid of this issue?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: It starts python shell saying `Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:18:03) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>`

Comment: **Do not** override the default system python on RHEL/CentOS (which is what AWS is based on). It will not work (for exactly reasons like this). The way to fix this issue is to remove your broken symlink.

Comment: @EtanReisner: any clue for fixing broken symlink?

Comment: Remove it. It was a mistake to create it. If you overwrote a file/link when you created it then you will need to recreate that file/link too. What does `rpm -qfV /usr/bin/python` say? What does `rpm -qf --dump /usr/bin/python | grep bin/python` say about the file?